# Pass props between siblings (React)

Tags: reactjs

I've got this functional component

```
import React from 'react'

function Header(){
    return(
        <div className='header'>
            <h2>Logo</h2>
            <p>Log In</p> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

When I will clicked on "Log In" I want to change my background-color in this class in class 'MainContainer'. Im a beginner in React. How Can I do it?

```
import React from 'react'
import RegistrationForm from '../LoginPage/RegistrationForm'
import './style2.scss'

class Main extends React.Component{

    constructor(param){
        super(param)

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="mainContainer">

                <RegistrationForm/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Main
```

EDIT: Here is the class where I called this classes:

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './components/LoginPage/Header'
import Main from './components/LoginPage/Main'


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Main/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: where is the Header component being called? Is it inside Main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Props can be passed from parent to child, not between siblings. So make a state in the App component and pass it down to `Main` and `Header`.

#### App

```
function App() {
const [loggingIn, setLoggingIn] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <Header setLoggingIn={setLoggingIn} />
      <Main loggingIn={loggingIn} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### Main

```
class Main extends React.Component{

    constructor(param){
        super(param)

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="mainContainer" style={{ background: this.props.loggingIn ? 'red' : 'inherit' }}>

                <RegistrationForm/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

#### Header

```
function Header({ setLoggingIn }){
    return(
        <div className='header'>
            <h2>Logo</h2>
            <p onClick={() => setLoggingIn(true)}>Log In</p> 
        </div>
    )
}
```